# Jmeter : Save Responses to a file doesn't append responses in a file

Tags: jmeter

### Listener :Save Responses in a file

Problem :
When i execute load test , it generates 3 types of file .
1).json 2).plain and 3).known

Suppose we have 2 errors that should come in .json file, then one error overwrites other error in .json file.

How can we append responses in a file?

Answer (score 1):

As of [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5) appending the results into the same file using [Save Responses to a file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener is not supported, you will either have to use

- different listeners with different prefixes to store the data into different files
- amend [JMeter results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) to store response data like:

  ```
  jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
  jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true
  ```
- switch to [JSR223 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) where you have full flexibility with regards to what to store, when, where and how. Example code which will append the results into `failures.json` file for all the failed samplers would be:

  ```
  if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
      new File('failures.json') << prev.getResponseDataAsString() << System.getProperty('line.separator')
  }
  ```

Comment: I have tried, JSr223 Listener as u suggested, I am able to track failure responses in a single file. thanks

Comment: is there any specific reason to use  .json extension file.